# Highstock bar rounded markers in new version

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, highcharts, gantt-chart

We have upgraded our higstock version from v1.2.5 to the latest (v1.3.9).
We have had to do many minor tweaks and changes, which we have now sorted to make it work as it did before, however, there are a couple of issues that remain and are proving hard to resolve.

The **first** is rounded end points on one of our bar charts;

postimg.org/image/6uqvr5szd
(The highlighted end points used to be flat and not overlap)

postimg.org/image/426uym7eh
(How it looks in old version (preferred))

The **second** (which seems like it could be related) is as follows;

postimg.org/image/n0gyaz9cr
(Again more roundedness)

postimg.org/image/yuncfy43b/
(How it looks in old version (preferred))

I have checked borderRadius, symbol, marker settings etc. etc. but nothing obvious is causing these issues.

Furthermore we have many other types of charts which all seem to be fine.

NB:
The second issues are an attempt at a basic Gantt chart as described by Torstein Hønsi in this post;

http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart

(I would also have added the images here, or the links, but StackOverflow forbid it because of my low reputation!)

As always, any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you reproduce your examples as live demos, because defaulty radius are not adapted.

Comment: Sebastian, I could arrange for you to have a temporary login to the website if that would help.
The backbone of the website is rather complex, so would take quite a while to reproduce.
Let me know if this is acceptable?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Will be better if you isolate your problem on jsfiddle.net